# Notification is coming sometimes and sometimes not coming when the app is in foreground using firebase notifications in Flutter for android

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, agora.io

I am using firebase messaging as firebase notifications plugin in flutter to send and receive notifications. But when I trigger the notification from one phone to other,it triggers but notification is not being fetched in other phone when app is in background. And OnMessage does not receive any notification on other phone I am not able to understand why it is happening sometime and not everytime
I here by put my notifications code here for you to understand how I had done this

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:mangoo/ui/Calls/VideoCall/calls.dart';
import 'package:mangoo/ui/Calls/VoiceCall/voice_call.dart';

class FirebaseNotifications {
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

//  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  BuildContext context;

  void setUpFirebase(BuildContext context) {
    print("in Firebase Setup");
//    _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
    this.context = context;
//    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
//    firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners();
    initNotification();
  }

  initNotification() {
    print("initNotification ")

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on messagemessage ${message}');
        if (message.containsKey('data')) {
          String channel_name = message['data']['channel_name'];
          String phoneNumber = message['data']['phone_number'];
          String screen_id = message['data']['screen_id'];
          if (screen_id == "0") {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => CallPage(
                  channelName: channel_name,
                  phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else if (screen_id == "1") {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => VoiceCallPage(
                  channelName: channel_name,
                  phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }

        // initialise the plugin. app_icon needs to be a added as a drawable resource to the Android head project
//        displayNotification(message);
//        Navigator.push(
//            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CallPage()));
        // _showItemDialog(message);
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
//        print('on backgroundmessage ${message}');
//      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on messageResume ${message}');
//        displayNotification(message);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on messageLaunch ${message}');
//        displayNotification(message);
      },
    );
  }


  Widget ShowDialog(String channelName, String phoneNumber) {
    return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 50,
                child: Text("Incoming Video call")),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5.0,
            ),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => CallPage(
                            channelName: channelName,
                            phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
//                  textColor: Colors.black,
                    child: Text(
                      "ACCEPT",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                  ),
                  VerticalDivider(
                    width: 3,
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text(
                      "REJECT",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the notifications were delivered sometimes and I found an easy work around to that just define your `myBackgroundMessageHandler` as:

```
Future<void> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      // SharedPreferences could have been modified in the UI isolate, so we have to fetch it from the host platform.
      await prefs.reload();
}
```

You can also go through this blog which explains how to setup firebase messaging on Flutter https://medium.com/@sylvainduch/firebase-messaging-catch-them-all-3f9c594734d7